# How can I rearrange a formula containing both cot and cosec?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to rearrange the following:

$$\cot{\theta}-\csc{\theta}=\dfrac{2B\mu}{bmg}$$

to get $\theta$.

I am unsure how to reduce a cot and cosec sum. Are there any maths tricks or identities that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\cot \theta-\csc \theta &=-\frac{1-\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}\\\\
&=-\frac{2\sin^2(\theta/2)}{\sin(2\theta/2)}\\\\
&=-\frac{2\sin^2(\theta/2)}{2\sin (\theta/2)\cos (\theta/2)}\\\\
&=-\tan (\theta/2)
\end{align}$$

So, we have the identity

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\cot \theta-\csc \theta =-\tan (\theta/2)}$$

which can be directly applied to the problem of interest.

Comment: This is the identity that I used in the end. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  And very pleased to hear.

Answer (score 3):

If $\cot \theta - \csc\theta = (\cos\theta - 1)/\sin\theta = k$ then

$$\frac{(\cos\theta-1)^2}{1-\cos^2\theta} = k^2$$

Thus

$$(1+k^2)\cos^2\theta - 2\cos\theta + (1 - k^2) = 0$$

and

$$\cos\theta = 1 \text{ or } \frac{1-k^2}{1+k^2}$$

$\cos\theta = 1$ is ruled out by the original equation and thus

$$\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{1-k^2}{1+k^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Use $\csc ^2\theta-\cot^2 \theta =1$ i.e. $(\csc \theta-\cot \theta)(\csc \theta+\cot \theta) =1$

So you get that $(\csc \theta+\cot \theta)=\frac{1}{\frac{2B\mu}{bmg}}=\frac{bmg}{2B\mu}$

Adding we get, $\csc \theta=\frac{\frac{2B\mu}{bmg}+\frac{bmg}{2B\mu}}{2}$ and $\cot \theta=\frac{\frac{bmg}{2B\mu}-\frac{2B\mu}{bmg}}{2}$

We can solve for $\theta$ from this easily.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cot\theta - \csc \theta = k$$
$$\cot\theta \pm \sqrt{\cot^2 \theta+1} = k$$
$$\pm \sqrt{\cot^2 \theta+1} = k-\cot\theta$$
$$\cot^2 \theta+1 = (k-\cot\theta)^2$$
$$\cot^2 \theta+1 = k^2-2k\cot\theta+\cot^2\theta$$
$$1 = k^2-2k\cot\theta$$
$$\cot\theta = \frac{k^2-1}{2k}$$